# xampp - can access control panel, cannot access projects/sites on local network

Tags: localhost, xampp, local-area-network

I've configured xampp and firewall so I can access desktop pc's localhost over my local network through desktop pc's IP.
But I'm not able to access auctual projects:

I can access:

`http://192.168.x.x/xampp` or `http://192.168.x.x/phpMyAdmin`

But I cannot access:

```
http://192.168.x.x/myWebsite/
```

I get an error:

```
Server error

We're sorry! The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Please try again later.

error 500
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Take a look at your XAMPP's Apache logs and post them here. It'll help diagnose what's going on

Comment: [Thu Jun 28 22:26:13 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.103] client denied by server configuration: D:/xampp/htdocs/peixa/log/

Comment: It's the last one, but I've found another in that folder:

Comment: Access denied for user 'peixa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I think I need "forward" my desktop pc's IP to localhost, don't I?

Comment: It looks like xampp is requiring password authentication, what authentication are you using?

Comment: It may just be a lack of permissions to /htdocs/peixa

Comment: None, I've turn everything of...but this might be problem 'peixa'@'localhost' - the localhost. Shouldn't it be 'peixa'@'192.168.x.x'?

Comment: I think the cause is the service account lacking permissions to D:/xampp/htdocs/peixa/log/. If the service does not have sufficient permissions to write to the log file, then I would expect a 500 error or something like 'client denied by server configuration'. Is peixa the name of the service user? Whatever user it is, did you verify Read-Write permissions to D:/xampp/htdocs/peixa/log/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server in XAMP answered with a HTTP 500 error, so you most certainly can access the projects/sites. The problem is that you have some sort of error in your code.

If you see any response at all then the web server is up and running, and you can stop worrying about Firewalls and that kind of thing.

Apache is giving an error, so you need to look in your Apache error log to see what is going on. A 500 error is a generic error you get when ever any sort of CGI of any form fails to return output to the web server. It's about as generic an error as you can get. The logs however will contain the exact error message, and that should help you track the problem down.

Comment: I think it has something to do with MySQL connection, because: Access denied for user 'peixa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Ah - no thinking about it - your MySQL permissions are wrong. MySQL is telling Apache to get stuffed when it tried to connect. You need to use a GRANT statement in MySQL to assign the correct permissions.

Comment: @BartB nailed it, take a look at the mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 1):

That seems like mysql connection problem.
You are probably using wrong info, username or password to connect with.
Try editing configuration file at /myWebsite/ to match correct info, if there is one.

Comment: Yes, I have the same thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause is the apache service account lacking permissions to *D:/xampp/htdocs/peixa/log/*.

If the service does not have sufficient permissions to write to the log file, then I would expect a 500 error or something like 'client denied by server configuration'.

Is *peixa* the name of the service user?

Whatever user, did you verify Read-Write permissions to *D:/xampp/htdocs/peixa/log/* ?

Comment: There was a log file with this error: Access denied for user 'peixa'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: So the user peixa has permissions?

Comment: Yes, it's a service user, it has permissions

Comment: I coufused with 'localhost', because I'm connecting remotely

Comment: You are remote, but the server is connecting to itself. Usually mysql will only accept connections from itself for security reasons.

Comment: Is it posible to change it?

Comment: You mean allow direct connections to mysql from the Internet? Yes, you can do that, but be careful. Here is a tutorial: http://julianschrader.de/20090218-mysql-how-to-allow-connections-from-outside-of-localhost/